# How can I display a path using string variables in python?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

So I want to make an application that takes files from one directory and then replace a file in another directory with that file. I have been trying to figure out how to take the string variables and display them as a path string. I do know that `os.replace()` doesn't accept string variables so I tried making a variable that takes the string variable and turns it into a string.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry("600x600")

def search1():
    global file1_path
    filename1 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    file1_path.set(filename1)
    print(filename1)

def search2():
    global file2_path
    filename2 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    file2_path.set(filename2)
    print(filename2)

def browse_button():
    global folder_path
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    folder_path.set(filename)
    print(filename)

def replacefile():
    os.replace(f'{folder}/game/scripts.rpa', f'{file1}')
    os.replace(f'{folder}/game/images.rpa', f'{file2}')

folder_path = StringVar()
file1_path = StringVar()
file2_path = StringVar()

file1 = str(file1_path)
file2 = str(file2_path)
folder = str(folder_path)

button1 = ttk.Button(text="Browse", command=search1)
button1.place(relx = 1.1, rely = 1.01)
button1.place(relx = .6, rely = .5)

button3 = ttk.Button(text="Browse", command=search2)
button3.place(relx = 1.1, rely = 1.01)
button3.place(relx = .6, rely = .54)

button4 = ttk.Button(text="Browse", command=browse_button)
button4.place(relx = 1.1, rely = 1.01)
button4.place(relx = .6, rely = .58)

button2 = ttk.Button(text="Replace", command=replacefile)
button2.place(relx = 0.01, rely = 1.01)
button2.place(relx = 0.01, rely = .8)

mainloop()
```

It brings up this error in console when I try to replace:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'PY_VAR0/game/scripts.rpa' -> 'PY_VAR1'
```

Python sees this as just a variable rather than part of string. I'm kinda new to python so I have no idea why this is happening. If anybody knows how I can fix this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you press ```replace``` it comes up with this in the console command prompt behind the window.

Comment: The 3 browse buttons have you choose a file or a folder and then are tried to be implemented in the string the path is typed once you press the replace button. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/642104909147275294/670797048232148992/Capture_LI.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three statements:

```
file1 = str(file1_path)
file2 = str(file2_path)
folder = str(folder_path)
```

will assign the names of the `StringVar` to the three variables, not the content of the `StringVar`.

You should get the content of the `StringVar` inside `replacefile()` function:

```
def replacefile():
    os.replace(f'{folder_path.get()}/game/scripts.rpa', f'{file1_path.get()}')
    os.replace(f'{folder_path.get()}/game/images.rpa', f'{file2_path.get()}')
```

Comment: Thanks it helped fix my error however when i try to replace the files it just deletes them and doesn't replace the file, but I might need to do a little more research before I come back frustrated and post another question.